# How to install entity framework core to asp.net core 3 project using visual studio code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a new MVC application using visual studio code and I want to add entity framework core to my project. My application is using the latest .net core 3 but when I tried to install package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` its show an error like this

> Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (>= 3.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I was using this '**dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --version 3.0.0**' to install the package, I got this from nuget.org. But still not working.

Comment: What is HealtcarePortal ? What kind of project is this ?

Comment: @Fabjan HealtcarePortal is my project name and this is an asp.net core mvc project

Comment: Does your project have a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` in it? It might be an incompatibility with that that's causing this problem.

Comment: @Eifion I don't have any reference in it, Entity Framework core should be the first reference for my project.

Comment: @codeken Take a look at your project's `csproj` file to see which packages are referenced.

Comment: @codeken could you past here the code from your csproj file?

Comment: `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>`

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core 3.0 removes some assemblies that were previously part of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package reference.

You should add the package references for removed assemblies.

In XML project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>My-secret</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#add-package-references-for-removed-assemblies).

Comment: when I try to copy it to .csproj and run dotnet restore, it gives me an error like this  `Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 3.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'` same also to all.

Comment: It could be a problem of the local cache try on the console > dotnet nuget locals --clear all

Comment: still not working, I have searched all over the internet but all the same result.